# Android check with NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run the ./gradlew clean check but I'm facing the following error:

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:50)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension$loadProcessors$efficientProcessorLoader$1.doLoadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:83)
... more ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

There's anything that could be missing on gradle configuration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I uninstall the Java 11 and install the java 8

Comment: @BrunoDiegoMartins Thanks man, It worked. Eric java 11 currently is not supported by Android Studio, so there may be some conflicts or dependencies.

Comment: Has anyone a solution to compile with a recent java release?

Comment: Android still requires Java 8. As for what happened JAXB has been removed from Java SE. There are JAXB-like third party libraries. But using Java 8 resolves the issue. Further, go into Android Studio Project Structure and rather than using java9 select android-studio/jre

Comment: I got this "please choose a valid jdk 11 directory" and cannot set java 8 to project

Answer (score 7):

Update your gradle version in project level gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.x.x'
```

OR

Change File->Project Structure->SDK Location->JDK path to jdk 1.8 location "Home" folder which should be installed in your system.

Comment: Updating solved this error for me, cheers.

Comment: This works for me

Change File->Project Structure->SDK Location->JDK path to jdk 1.8 location

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Android Studio 3.6 or later go to *Project Structure* -> *SDK Location* and change JDK Location. Android Studio comes with default JRE. It is available in dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall **Java 11** and install the **java 8**

"i installed [jre8](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) && [jdk8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)"

Then open **Project Structure** and change **SDK Location** to the new **JDK Location**

Answer (score 1):

Check for updates on the gradle plugin, that fixed the problem for me.